# how to create a class from a variable with a namespace

Tags: php

```
$c = 'MyClass';

$obj = new $c(); // its ok
```

Now I want to make the same with a namespace:

```
$c = 'MyClass';

$obj = new \my\namespace\$c(); // syntax error, unexpected '$c'(T_VARIABLE)
```

how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to define the namespace with the variable in its own string (note "namespace" is a reserved word, not a valid namespace - changed in this example):

```
$c = 'MyClass';
$fqcn = '\\my\\namespaceXYZ\\' . $c;

$obj = new $fqcn();
```

Comment: nice :)))))))))